# How to select a class with a space before the name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem. I want to modify the css of a particular div. That division is being generated dynamically. The output is this:

```
<div class=" class-name"></div>
```

Apparently, there is a space before the class name. I tried using:

```
$(".class-name").html("test");
```

But my code wont work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it in the class name without the space? Just so you can be sure that this **is** the issue.

Comment: *"Apparently, there is a space before the class name"* No, there's a space in the attribute, but the attribute is a space-delimited set of class names. So the class on the element is actually `class-name` (without the space).

Comment: It definitely works with a space, regardless of whether the div is generated dynamically, as long as you run the code after the div exists: http://jsfiddle.net/hREVy/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The space does not matter. You either have not got jQuery loaded or else or not waiting unitl the code is ready.

```
$(function(){
     $(".class-name").html("test");
});
```

To help you debug for next time, install firebug on firefox and in the console an error might show up.

Comment: The question says the div _"is being generated dynamically",_ so using a ready handler probably won't help. You said _"in the console an error will show up"_ - Not for the OP's code. It doesn't have a syntax or runtime error, it just has (we're assuming) a logical error of being run before the element is available.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is true assuming he has loaded jQuery but he might get an error that `$` is undefined! Will edit to `might` though.

Comment: Good point. And of course I didn't mean to discourage the OP from checking the console - that is always a good plan when code isn't working as expected.